# Задать параметр в JPA Repository

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hql

Нужно из базы даних вытянуть топ категорий по их рейтингу. Например: "SELECT category_name FROM category ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT ?" вместо знака вопроса должен передаваться входной параметр.
[image: Вместо 4 должен передаться параметр]

Comment: В зависимости от драйверов к БД параметры в части лимит могут не привязываться. если у вас именно эта проблема, т придется подставлять самому значение непосредственно в текст запроса

Comment: Вот и вопрос, как вставить в запрос параметр?

Comment: А как у вас текстовые строки конкатенируются ? если вдруг знаком `+` то `"SELECT ... LIMIT "+count` возможно count надо привести к строке, опять же любым принятым в вашем языке способом

Comment: А если вы используете для запросов hibernate то google по запросу `hibernate limit` возвращает массу предложений на подобии `.setFirstResult(firstResult).setMaxResults(limit)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LIMIT не поддерживается HQL. 
Поэтому используется следующий пример:

// SQL: SELECT * FROM table LIMIT start, maxRows;

```
Query q = session.createQuery("FROM table");
q.setFirstResult(start);
q.setMaxResults(maxRows);
```